# LSAT questions help needed, where to ask?

Tags: criminal-law, employment

Where can I ask questions when I need help with the Law School Admission Test ([LSAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_School_Admission_Test))? I am trying to practice LSAT questions and I have some problems with it.